# how to extract all prefix words from an ispell .mwl file in bash

Tags: bash, perl, ispell

I have an ispell huge .mwl file and I want to remove all the ispell suffixes to generate a simple text-only words dictionnary
using unix ispell, bash or perl commands.

Is there ispell command options to do that? 

(in unix, the .mwl.gz files are located in the /usr/share/ispell/ directory)

a short extract non exhaustive of the file:

```
a/MRSY
A'asia
a'body
a'thing
aaa
AAAS
Aaberg/M
Aachen/M
Aaedon/M
AAeE
AAeE's
aaerially
aaerialness
Aaerope/M
AAgr/M
aah/DGS
aal/MS
Aalborg
Aalesund
aalii/MS
Aaliyah/M
Aalst/M
Aalto
aam
Aandahl/M
Aani/M
Aaqbiye/M
Aar/MN
Aara/M
Aarau
aardvark/MS
aardwolf/M
aardwolves
Aaren/M
Aargau
aargh
Aarhus
Aarika/M
aarogramme
```

Comment: Please take a look at [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: A sample of data from a mwl file would be useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you mean by suffix but I'll assume it's the part following the / or ' in your sample text.  You can do this with a simple pipeline from Bash.

```
cat something.mwl | perl -pe 's{[/\x27].*$}{}; ' > stripped_something.txt
```

The `-p` switch means to run perl in a pipeline.  Whatever you pipe in will be put into `$_` one line at a time, worked on, and then printed out.  Notice I put `\x27` for the apostrophe in the regex.  Escaping it in the command line is a big pain.  If there are any other characters that start a suffix you can put them in the character class.

You can do any other work on the line before printing it out this way too.

See the [perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun) documentation for more about the `-p` switch.